# Flutter SDK path problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

I have imported a Flutter project and it was asking to locate SDK path. I have previously created and developed some Flutter projects in my own system, so when I checked the SDK path in those files and I tried pointing to the same path folder and was not accepting it as a Flutter SDK folder.

Existing project sdk path
[image]

I tried running flutter doctor in terminal
[image]

But unable to set SDK path for the new imported project file, the paths I tried to point is
/Users/Siva/Documents/Development/flutter and /Users/Siva/Documents/Development/flutter/bin

How to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Terminal is using zsh while Visual Studio Code is using bash. Simplest fix would be to just set zsh as Visual Studio Code's default shell.

If you really want to use bash in VSC make sure you have your PATH configured for both shells. I typically put all my PATH adjustments in `~/.profile` and source that from `~/.zprofile` and `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
# ~/.profile

...

export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export FLUTTER_ROOT="$HOME/Documents/Development/flutter"
export PATH="$PATH":"$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin"

...
```

```sh
# ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc

source ~/.profile

...
```

```sh
# ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.profile

...
```